# Dependency Injection и Standalone application

Tags: java

Доброго всем времени! Народ, у меня простой вопрос - как использовать @EJB вместо JNDI lookup-a? Чтобы экземпляр бина 100% инициализировался через инжэкшн, а не кидал NullPointerException при его вызове. Я создал два проекта: серверную часть и клиента-standalone. Вот они...

Серверная часть:

[image]

```
@Remote
public interface EchoRemote{
    String getMessage();
}
```

---

```
@Stateless
public class EchoBean implements EchoRemote{
    @Override
    public String getMessage(){
        return "Hello From Stateless Bean";
    }
}
```

---

```
public class InvokationClient{
    @EJB
    private EchoRemote bean;

    public String getMessage(){
        return bean.getMessage();
    }
}
```

Standalone-client:

```
import com.steeplesoft.client.InvokationClient;
public class Main{
    public static void main( String... args ) throws IOException{
        InvokationClient client = new InvokationClient();

        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter( "D:/invokation_client_test.txt" );
        fileWriter.write( client.getMessage() );
        fileWriter.close();
    }
}
```

Создается пустой файл, а в консоли - NullPointerException.
Почему не происходит inject?

Comment: видимо потому что аннотация `EJB` относится к `J2EE` что подразумевает что приложение должно крутится на сервере. для того чтоб это работало в `standalone` приложении надо использовать что-то на подобии `spring`

Comment: ну, у меня же по сути инжектится при старте сервера или, во всяком случае, должно... разве не?

Answer (score 2):

Standalone clients or non-managed POJOs(POJOs which are not maintained by Containers) do not support annotation injection. So @EJB will not work. This must be a Java EE Application Client (another type of Java EE module that allows to wrap a Java SE application, deploy it to an application server and make use of deployed EJB, platform services and resources) and Java EE Application Client Main-Class does support injection of resources in static annotated fields or methods.

Comment: хах)) а ссылку можно?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4078148/ejbs-with-main-what-is-this-all-about